# SQL command runs fine, results don't update

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've taken the code from here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases

Modified it to work with my database and it updates the table properly. I can see this part work in debug mode. However when I try to get it to modify the database it chugs through the code without any actual update or error. How can I debug something that runs fine?

Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\CorrectFileLocation\Database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    Dim sSelAllCmd As String = "Select * From List_Tbl"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sSelAllCmd, connection)
    Dim indextable As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(indextable)

    Dim update As New SqlCommand("UPDATE List_Tbl SET List_Index = @List_Index WHERE List_Id = @List_Id" , connection)

    update.Parameters.Add("@List_Index", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
    update.Parameters("@List_Index").Value = 99
    update.Parameters.Add("@List_Id", SqlDbType.BigInt)
    update.Parameters("@List_Id").Value = 2

    adapter.UpdateCommand = update

    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey

    adapter.Update(indextable)

End Sub
```

End Class

Viewing indextable during debugging shows the proper table. The table is name dbo.List_Tbl. Do I need dbo for the update function?

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ List_Id ║ List_Index ║ Stuff  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║       1 ║          4 ║ Name A ║
║       2 ║          5 ║ Name B ║
║       3 ║          6 ║ Name C ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adapter.Update()` can be used to update the **database** once you modify your `DataTable` object.

If you want to just execute a SQL Update do the following:

```
Using connection
    connection.Open()
    update.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

So the final code will look as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\CorrectFileLocation\Database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    Dim sSelAllCmd As String = "Select * From List_Tbl"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sSelAllCmd, connection)
    Dim indextable As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(indextable)

    Dim update As New SqlCommand("UPDATE List_Tbl SET List_Index = @List_Index WHERE List_Id = @List_Id" , connection)

    update.Parameters.Add("@List_Index", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
    update.Parameters("@List_Index").Value = 99
    update.Parameters.Add("@List_Id", SqlDbType.BigInt)
    update.Parameters("@List_Id").Value = 2

     Using connection
         connection.Open()
         update.ExecuteNonQuery()
     End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataAdapter class executes the UpdateCommand only if the table passed has rows with the `RowState` property set to `Modified`.

You have just read your indexTable and so, the property `RowState` for all rows is set to `Unchanged`. In this scenario, during the `adapter.Update` call the UpdateCommand is not executed becase there is nothing to update. (The same is true for InsertCommand and DeleteCommand that work with the corresponding properties)

If your intention is to change directly a particular row, then you don't need the adapter services at all. You could call directly ExecuteNonQuery on the SqlCommand

```
Dim update As New SqlCommand(@"UPDATE List_Tbl 
                               SET List_Index = @List_Index 
                               WHERE List_Id = @List_Id" , connection)

update.Parameters.Add("@List_Index", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
update.Parameters("@List_Index").Value = 99
update.Parameters.Add("@List_Id", SqlDbType.BigInt)
update.Parameters("@List_Id").Value = 2
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: He got in first and has like 1/1000 your rep. You're obviously very talented at this too!